# Can we say that the following sentence is Mixed conditional?

Tags: conditionals

As far as I know typical mixed conditionals is like
"If I were you, I would have bought the red dress."
You use the past tense in the if-clause, and the past perfect in the main clause.

But how about the following sentence "If God asks me what my wish is, I would say that "It is my country's independence."
This sentence uses the present tense in the if-clause, and the past tense in the main clause.
Can we see this sentence as one of the mixed conditionals.
I'd appreciate your answer.

Comment: What do you plan to do with whatever answer you may get for this question? You're talking about an ESL oversimplification of how English works that no native speaker is ever taught and no linguist pays any attention to because it is meaningless. It is a harmful thing to learn because it is not an accurate model of how English works. Real English has hundreds of combinations. These have neither names nor numbers.

Comment: I would say "If God were to ask me..." anyway.

Answer (score 1):

"If God asks me" is a conditional *future* event, because he hasn't asked you *yet*. It is essentially the same as saying "If God *were to ask* me".

In your second clause you go on to say what you *would* do in the future. So, this is not an example of a mixed conditional, because both clauses are future events.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it probably is a mixed conditional (although it depends on the definition given by your workbook; as tchrist said in the comments, linguists and native speakers don't use the concept).

"If God asks me, I will ..." is the first conditional - i.e. present tense in the "if" clause, a future expression in the result clause.

"If God asked me [*or* were to ask me], I would ..." is the second conditional - i.e. past tense in the "if" clause, a conditional expression (with "would") in the result clause.

If you mix and match, that's a mixed conditional.

For this sentence, I find that the unmixed forms sound better.